# Словообразовательная цепочка слова "мгновенье"

Tags: словообразование

Словообразовательная цепочка для **мгновенье**.
Сложный вопрос для меня. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ***мгновенье (мгновение)*** в современном языке не делится на морфемы и считается непроизводным.

Но можно составить этимологическую словообразовательную цепочку:

**миг — миг/ну/ть — мг/н/овени/е.**

**Составной суффикс ОВ+ЕНИ**  используется при образовании существительных от глаголов, например: с/толк/ну/ть/ся — с/толк/н/овени/е, при/кос/ну/ть/ся — при/кос/н/овени/е.